# how to call or mimic a javascript function inside a webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, xamarin

I am making a hybrid app. I am using xamarin for android, pretty much the same as android. I have already figured out how to hook the phone's back button press. When pressed I want my app code to either mimic or call a javascript function that is part of the webpage that the webview is displaying. It is my web page, so I know the code that the webview is rendering. To be specific, I want to call a jquery slideToggle function on a page element when the phone's back button is pressed. Can that be done, and if so what would be the best approach? I'm hoping that someone here has had to do something just like this in the past. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think webview supports JQuery, unless maybe you reference it.

The Xamarin android way of doing it is:

```
 webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
 webView.loadData("", "text/html", null);
 webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(injectedObject.toString())");
```

Source : [Android.Webkit.WebView.AddJavascriptInterface Method](http://docs.mono-android.net/api/member/Android.Webkit.WebView.AddJavascriptInterface(Java.Lang.Object,System.String)/)

Also make sure you have enabled Javascript,

```
 web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
```

You can show or hide the element by finiding it by id (`document.FindElementById`). Then you can set its `display` to `block` or `none`. Thus you can do it purely in Javascript.

**Add on :**

There are couple of problems with your method. To name a few -

- on pressing of back button user expects a particular behavior and it should not be  altered. This would not give a rich user experience.
- if you are override ing the back button press then what about the navigation bar menu click.
- JavaScript way of doing can cause security issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and maybe it's the only right one.I have seen that in the documentation and I have also seen the security warnings about it. So the person that I advised about this matter believes that there must be another way to do this. Is there?

Comment: I have slightly updated the answer. See if it now addresses all your problems.

Comment: I marked it as the right answer because to my knowledge and from what the documentation says, this is the only way to do it.

Comment: Try it out in real and get back if you face any problems. Also i think there is a bug with 2.3 version simulator if you are using this.